# mongo db throws error trying to edit _id field in update

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to update a document

`final Update update = new Update();
update.set("id", String.valueOf(partnerId));
update.pushAll("appIds", appIds.toArray());
mongoTemplate.upsert(Query.query(Criteria.where("partnerId").is(partnerId)), update, PartnerAppIds.class);`

On executing this getting this error
`{  "err" : "After applying the update to the document {_id: \"66\" , ...}, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: \"5}`

The document looks like this

```
public class PartnerAppIds {
@Indexed
private String id;

@Indexed
private Long partnerId;

@Indexed
private Set<String> appIds;

public Long getPartnerId() {
    return partnerId;
}

public void setPartnerId(Long partnerId) {
    this.partnerId = partnerId;
}

public Set<String> getAppIds() {
    return appIds;
}

public void setAppIds(Set<String> appIds) {
    this.appIds = appIds;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

My question is as I have a id field, why mongo is assuming i am updating '_id' field, where as I am updating the id field here. Are _id and id same for mongo here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.id-handling),

> A property or field without an annotation but named id will be mapped
>   to the _id field.
>
> When querying and updating MongoTemplate will use the converter to
>   handle conversions of the Query and Update objects that correspond to
>   the above rules for saving documents so field names and types used in
>   your queries will be able to match what is in your domain classes.

So use field with different name other than _id or id if you need to update.